# What is the difference between payment transactions and in-app purchases?

Tags: in-app-purchase, payment-gateway, payment, in-app-billing, in-app-subscription

Suppose there is an app that lets you enroll to courses in exchange of a subscription fee. If there is any difference between the two, which one to use?

Comment: The difference between the subscritpion fee model and what else? You don't talk about anything else.

Comment: In case of in-app purchases, do we need to pay a certain percentage to Google? If yes, then is it same for payment transactions?